# XPath 1.0 Code Selects Wrong Maximum Value

Tags: xpath

I am trying to use XPath 1.0 to select the maximum double value in an XML document. I understand that XPath 1.0 doesn't support the Max function that would make this extremely easy, but the system I'm using only supports XPath 1.0 functions.

I'm not able to post the entire file due to length, but here is a sample of the document I'm scanning: https://codebeautify.org/xmlviewer/cbc93c7e.

I've tried this XPath Expression:

```
/site/forecast/datum[not(primary < preceding-sibling::datum/primary) and not (primary < following-sibling::datum/primary)]
```

But no matter what, it returns the wrong datum. It always returns:

```
<datum>
    <valid timezone="UTC">2019-04-04T06:00:00-00:00</valid>
        <primary name="Stage" units="ft">9.80</primary>
        <secondary name="Flow" units="cfs">3010.00</secondary>
        <pedts>HGIFE</pedts>
</datum>
```

I expect it to return the element with the maximum "primary stage" value like:

```
<datum>
    <valid timezone="UTC">2019-03-28T18:00:00-00:00</valid>
        <primary name="Stage" units="ft">13.10</primary>
        <secondary name="Flow" units="cfs">13400.00</secondary>
        <pedts>HGIFE</pedts>
</datum>
```

I understand it will return all those with the 13.10 primary stage, but that's okay. I'll select the first one it returns if I can just get it to that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do note that you might have more than one maximum. Use:

```
/site/forecast/datum[not(primary < ../datum/primary)][1]
```

This select the element

```
<datum> 
  <valid timezone="UTC">2019-03-28T18:00:00-00:00</valid>  
  <primary name="Stage" units="ft">13.10</primary>  
  <secondary name="Flow" units="cfs">13400.00</secondary>  
  <pedts>HGIFE</pedts> 
</datum>
```

Test it in http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/4256aac47f4f0efc36e23a2f16183d90